# Существует ли разница?

Tags: фразеология

Существует ли принципиальная разница между словосочетаниями "договориться о встрече" и "планировать встречу"?

Answer (score 1):

Это не всегда одно и то же. **Договориться** о встрече можно только *совместно*, напр. в двустороннем порядке. Сроки встречи при этом не обязательно сразу оговариваются, напр. если это встреча официальных лиц, то на основании договорённости *о факте встречи* может начаться работа дипломатов по её **планированию** на конкретное время. Планирование встречи может начаться и *в одностороннем порядке*: одна из сторон может сначала запланировать себе достижение **договорённости** о встрече как таковой.